# Necessary requirements for current

Tags: electricity

So i was in a course yesterday and the "teacher" told us the following (which i had a hard time believing/understanding)

There is a load connected to a transformer. Applied potential difference is 230V.
The load is malfunctioning and the insulation isn't working anymore.
Now the guy told us there is no harm on touching the load, there will not be any current through the person into the ground.

His explanation was that there can't be any current because there isn't a closed loop.

imo the only requirements needed for current is a potential difference and a non-ideal insulation. U=R*I

i asked him how he would explain thunder as there isn't any closed loop during the discharge of the cloud.
Suffice to say, he didn't convince me.

Now can someone tell me what to believe? And maybe throw in a kind of explanation of why i'm wrong?

Thanks!

[image: Elecitrcal fault]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The teacher was right about the closed loop fact.**
The current can only pass through a closed lopp connecting two different levels of electrical potential. However in the case of thunder the potential differnce could be millions of volts, which ionize the gases between the cloud and the ground. The ionized gased behave as conductor providing the passage for the current and hence closing the lopp. Whereas 230 V can't ionize the gases to break the insulation.
Furthermore if you remove all the gases between the clouds and the ground there will be no thunders anymore.

Comment: But if you connect the insulation (which is at 230V) and the ground with a metal rod. will there not be current in the rod? earth potential isn't 230V imo

Comment: @McZoid but still the potential difference will be not high enough to cause a breakdown. The breakdown voltage of typical insulator is very high, so it should be safe to touch the load (not the uninsulated wire because in this case you will be the load) unless the insulation cover is damaged, however I am not encouraging you to experiment with that - safety protocol requires first to turn off the electric device and only after that to work with it

Comment: It is a purely hypotethical question. Also in the case studied, the insulation is damaged.

Comment: Replying to your comment: If you connect the +ve end of the source (insulation according to your comment) to the ground with a metal rod, ofcourse there will be a current flowing through the rod.

Comment: Well that was what it tought. Been in discussion with the teacher for half an hour about it. thx for the help!